# How to access the string variable outside the for loop in java?

Tags: java

for the following code which I worked on.Now the problem is  how do I access the variable string outside the for loop?Thank you.

```
for (String[] string: arr) {
    if(string.length == 1)
    { 
        System.out.println(string[0]);
        continue;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < string.length; i++)  {
        System.out.println(string[0] + " " + string[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't. It doesn't even make *sense* outside the loop. Which value would you expect to see?

Comment: Just because someone asks a quetion like this don't down rank him. That discourages learning.

Comment: I know I cant access it outside the loop.Is there any possible way to do so??

Comment: Declare another variable outside the loop, and assign this variable the desired value before terminating the loop. (I'm not sure what "the desired value" is supposed to be in this case - that's the important bit for you work out :D)

Comment: Desired value should be string[0] and string[i].Declaring another variable does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution provides you the arraylist of all the Strings that are printed. This provides an arraylist created with the string array logic to use it beond the `for loop`.

Use the finalList to print all the Strings even after the `for loop`.

```
ArrayList<String> finalList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String[] string: arr) {

        if(string.length == 1)
        { 
            System.out.println(string[0]);
            finalList.add(string[0]);
            continue;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < string.length; i++)  {
            System.out.println(string[0] + " " + string[i]);                
            finalList.add(string[0] + " " + string[i]);
        }   
    }

    for(String output: finalList){
        System.out.println(output);
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Your `string` variable is locally scoped and only exists within the loop.  You need to define an external `String[]` variable first, then make an assignment to that variable within the loop:

```
String[] outsideString;

for (String[] string: arr) {
  ...
  outsideString = string;
  ...
}

// This line works
System.out.println(outsideString[0]);
```

Comment: `outsideString` is of type `String`, `string` is of type `String[]`, so this code won't compile.

Comment: Note that, in this case, you may well overwrite 'outsideString' several times while inside your loop.  If you think you are going to need to access several Strings of interest that your loop processes, use a collection and add Strings you want outside of the loop to the collection.

Comment: maybe use += instead of just =

Answer (score 0):

You can't given this code. In the enhanced for loop that you have at the top you can only use that variable local to that for loop

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  If you need to access something from the loop outside of said loop, create a String or Collection variable outside of the loop and assign/add to it from inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String[] outerString  = {}; 

    for (String[] string: arr) {
        outerString = string;
        if(string.length == 1)
        { 
            System.out.println(string[0]);
            continue;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < string.length; i++)  {
            System.out.println(string[0] + " " + string[i]);
        }   
    }

    if(outerString.length > 0){
        System.out.println(outerString[0]);
    }
```

Do remember that only the last item in the Collection iteration will be printed in the outer string.

Comment: It works fine when its string[0]...but i need string[0]+ " "+ string[i] to be accessed outside the for loop..

Comment: Does this string[0]+ " "+ string[i]  to be printed for all the iterations of the for loop?

Comment: yes,I should be printed for all the iterations of the for loop.